# How to pass string to gets_s() in C++?

Tags: c++, string, gets

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str;
    gets_s(str);
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to run the above code it threw an error that no instance of `gets_s()` matched the argument list.
How can I pass an `std::string` instead of a `char[]` to `gets_s()` function if is possible?

Comment: Please add the code to your post.

Comment: Why do you even need that? Use it normal way: `cin >> str;`

Comment: `>>` is not an alternative to `gets_s`. The closest equivalent is `getline`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, there are a lot of answers about `std::getline`, but in case if you *really* need to use `get_s`, you may write such code:

```cpp
size_t length = 10; // Just for example
std::string my_string(length, 0);
get_s(&my_string[0], length); // C++14 and older
get_s(my_string.data(), length); // C++17 and newer
```

Comment: Noone really needs to use `get_s`. `std::getline` has been included since at least C++98.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's true, but maybe it is, for instance, a teacher's request in university :)

Comment: Then that teacher should be informed that using optional C functions isn't really very good. :-) In that case: `std::cin.getline(str.data(), length);` would be the C++ version.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov since C++17 `std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::data()` returns non-const pointer to underlying array: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data. Even for C++14 OP can use `&my_string[0]`, which causes no UB when memory was already allocated (it was done by calling a constructor that receives a size parameter).

Answer (score 3):

The C function [`get_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) takes a `char*` and a length argument, not a `std::string`.

Your best options are:

- Formatted input:

  ```
  std::cin >> str;
  ```
- Read a line:

  ```
  std::getline(std::cin, str);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. Use the stream in a normal way:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`gets_s` has a significant limitation in that you must provide an upper limit on the number of characters you want to read.

Since you are using `string` the superior alternative is to use `getline`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string str;
getline(cin, str);
```

This will expand the string to hold as many characters as are entered by the user.